# Using ValueTuple while compiling a class from text runtime

Tags: c#, codedom, valuetuple

I'm trying to compile a class from text at runtime. My problem is that my class uses a valueTupe in a function (AllLines), and I receive an error "C:\xxxx.cs(19,28): error CS0570: 'BaseClass.AllLines' is not supported by the language" when using this code

```
CodeDomProvider objCodeCompiler = new Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider();

CompilerParameters objCompilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();

objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.IO.dll");
objCompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Linq.dll");
CompilerResults objCompileResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(objCompilerParameters, filename);
```

EDIT:

The Textfile looks as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public List<(int LineNumber, string Value)> AllLines
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform v2.0.0.0, 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.0.0.50618

Unsure if that is the actual version of roslyn.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve], including the package versions you're using? (In particular, if you're using an old version of Roslyn, that would definitely explain it.)

Comment: Thanks. Done so, please see my edits. Unsure if that is my roslyn version.

Comment: Trying just the code there gives me an entirely different error. This is why I was asking for a complete example - something we can build and run really easily.

Comment: @george-alexandria : I see that in your review/edit, you removed the roslyn tag. Am I not using roslyn to compile the code, or what was the reason for suggesting the edit?

Comment: @DaisyShipton. So, your suggestion is inadvertently guiding me to the solution, I think. While making a small example to demonstrate my problem, using the same logic/idea, in the same project, I'm -not- getting the error, even though I'm still returning a named tuple. Thank you very much. Even though this doesn't answer my question, I can now start adding things and testing with a working example.

Comment: @WynDiesel, you directly use `CodeDom`, not `Roslyn`.

Comment: @WynDiesel: It's not really inadvertent - the process of coming up with a complete example *very* often solves the problem :)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeAlexandria, I was under the impression codeDom is roslyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you were correct that you were using Roslyn as you are using `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider` from the NuGet package [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform).

However, the issue you are facing is that your text file does not contain valid C#.

1. Your declaration of `List<T>` is invalid in enclosing the type parameters in parentheses
2. You are adding names(?) to the type parameter declaration (LineNumber, Value).
3. You're providing two type parameters when `List<T>` only accepts one. (Maybe you meant to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`)
4. There is no body to your property declaration

Try replacing your text file with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> AllLines
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you don't actually need `using System` or `using System.Linq` for this example. Also note, you don't need to use Roslyn for this. The old fashioned CodeDOM can compile it (replace `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider` with `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Andy. On points 1,2 and 3, C# 7 has a new feature called named tuples, which is used as per my example (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples). On point 4, you are correct, in my example i didnt supply code for the property. This wasn't my problem either. The file's code complies fine, there is not problem with the actual code. I still haven't figured out what the problem was, I ended up using CodeDom, as per your suggestion. In lack of a better answer, I am going to accept yours.